# Req.body.campo sigue siendo undefined

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, npm, requests

Hola que tal he leído sobre el problema undefined en el req.body.campo, y he tratado de solucionarlo, y ninguna de las soluciones me ha podido ayudar, solo me gustaría saber el por qué
he intentado con otros proyectos y sucede lo mismo, he seguido avanzando con

```
req.param("campo")
```

Pero esta deprecated, espero me puedan ayudar, sigue sin funcionar en otros proyectos, mi código de server es:

```
const express = require('express');
const app=new express();
const body = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const passport = require('./config/passport');


//middlewares
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(body.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(body.json());
app.use(cors());

//settings
app.set('port',process.env.PORT||3001);
//routes
//app.get('/user',require('./routes/user'));
app.post('/prueba',require('./routes/prueba'));
app.use('/users',require('./routes/user'));
app.use('/login',require('./routesLogin/UserLogin'));
app.use('/uploadFile',require('./routes/upload'));
```

Y si también tengo instalado body-parser:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^4.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bookshelf": "^1.1.0",
    "bookshelf-secure-password": "^5.0.0",
    "bookshelf-virtuals-plugin": "^0.1.1",
    "concurrently": "^5.1.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
  }
```

front-edn con react utilizo axios, el envío de parametros no hay probelma

```
 onSubmit=async(e)=> {
    e.preventDefault();
      await axios.post('users/', {
        nombre: this.state.nombre,
        apellido: this.state.apellido,
        correo: this.state.correo,
        fechaNac: this.state.fechaNac,
        usuario: this.state.usuario,
        password: this.state.password,
        db: this.state.db
      })
```

Y el back-end

```
 const usuar = new user({
        nombre: req.param('nombre'),
        apellido: req.param('apellido'),
        correo: req.param('correo'),
        fechaNac: req.param('fechaNac'),
        usuario: req.param('usuario'),
        password: req.param('password'),
        database:req.param('db')
    });
```

Cuando mando los campos y los recibo de esa forma en la consola me aparecen las alertas de dprecated, y me gustaría quitarlos para poder visualizar otros errores.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar la forma en la que envías los datos desde el front a tu aplicación?

Comment: Mh no creo que importe demasiado, también las estoy mandando desde postman. Pero pues bueno actualizo la pregunta, espero puedas encontrar una solución, ocupo react

Comment: porque haces un `new` de `express`.  Es sin el `new`. Así `const app = express();`. Y pondria los middlewares de cors y bodyparser antes que cualquier otro middleware.

Comment: `req.params` esta deprecated y deberías usar `req.params.campo`. Pero tampoco veo que desde react mandes un param en tu ruta. Un parametro es un valor que pases por url. Algo `/user/1`. El 1 es el param. No tiene mucho que ver con `body`

Comment: Agregando el new fue de un ejemplo que vi, si lo dejo sin el new sigue sin funcionar. Respecto a la ruta /user/1 no lo recibe así, recibe una arreglo json, clave valor, es un data que llega a back end, y sí cambie de posisción los middlewares de cors y body-parser pero sigue recibiendo undefined

Comment: El campo te da `undefined` o la propiedad `req.body`? Lo podrías comprobar con un console.log? De manera que sepamos que esta recibiendo el `req.body` completo.

Comment: La salida que mencionas desde postman es la siguiente: [object Object]

Comment: Estás hablando de cosas diferentes. Postman es un servicio para probar tu API. Tu problema no es lo que recibe Postman (`req.body` es en Express). Desde Postman solo debes asegurarte de enviar los datos como `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Si usas Express v4.17 en adelante no necesitas `body-parser` como dependencia, usa lo que te provee Express: `app.use(express.urlencoded())` y `app.use(express.json)`. Por lo demás, nada de lo que aportas permite reproducir el problema. Usas `axios` y la forma en que envías los datos se ve correcta. Saludos

Comment: Hola que tal, si se de que va postman y hago las pruebas en postman solo para saber si se puede recibir con req.body. pero sigo recibiendo undefined ó en su defecto { }. Realice otro proyecto siguiendo las indicaciones de la página oficial http://expressjs.com/es/api.html#req.body y sigue sin funcionar. Muchas graciaas todos por sus comentarios. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Los datos que envías en el `body` JSON llegan en la propiedad `request.body` y no en `request.param`. Puedes verlo en esta parte de la [documentación](http://expressjs.com/es/api.html#req.body).

Podrías intentar hacer la petición usando *Postman* o *cURL* para descartar que el error está en tu servidor. También en las herramientas de desarrollador de tu navegador puedes revisar que la petición hecha contiene los datos que enviaste desde *Axios*, sino el error está en tu frontend.

Comment: Hola que tal, leí la documentación de express como dos veces, lo mismo sucede con body-parser, acabo de intetar otro proyecto sencillo, req.body sigue siendo undefined. El error no puede estar en el front-end debido a que pues postman de la misma forma recibe como respuesta undefined.